# c++: Function that locks mutex for other function but can itself be executed in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex

I have a question regarding thread safety and mutexes. I have two functions that may not be executed at the same time because this could cause problems:

```
std::mutex mutex;

void A() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    //do something (should't be done while function B is executing)
}

T B() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    //do something (should't be done while function A is executing)
    return something;
}
```

Now the thing is, that function A and B should not be executed at the same time. That's why I use the mutex. However, it is perfectly fine if function B is called simultaneously from multiple threads. However, this is also prevented by the mutex (and I don't want this). Now, is there a way to ensure that A and B are not executed at the same time while still letting function B be executed multiple times in parallel?

Comment: Maybe use some kind of semaphore to track the number of current callers of each function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If C++14 is an option, you could use a shared mutex (sometimes called "reader-writer" mutex). Basically, inside function `A()` you would acquire a unique (exclusive, "writer") lock, while inside function `B()` you would acquire a shared (non-exclusive, "reader") lock.

As long as a shared lock exists, the mutex cannot be acquired *exclusively* by other threads (but can be acquired non-exclusively); as long as an exclusive locks exist, the mutex cannot be acquired by any other thread anyhow.

The result is that you can have several threads concurrently executing function `B()`, while the execution of function `A()` prevents concurrent executions of both `A()` and `B()` by other threads:

```
#include <shared_mutex>

std::shared_timed_mutex mutex;

void A() {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(mutex);
    //do something (should't be done while function B is executing)
}

T B() {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(mutex);
    //do something (should't be done while function A is executing)
    return something;
}
```

Notice, that some synchronization overhead will always be present even for concurrent executions of `B()`, and whether this will eventually give you better performance than using plain mutexes is highly dependent on what is going on inside and outside those functions - always measure before committing to a more complicated solution.

Boost.Thread also provides an implementation of `shared_mutex`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my compiler does not support C++ 14 yet.

Comment: @user1488118: As I mentioned in the answer, "Boost.Thread also provides an implementation of `shared_mutex`.". It should be enough to replace `std::` with `boost::` everywhere in the above code snippet (oh, and `std::shared_timed_mutex` with `boost::shared_mutex`).

Answer (score 0):

You have an option in C++14.
Use [`std::shared_timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex).

`A` would use [`lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex/lock), `B` would use [`lock_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex/lock_shared)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possibly full of bugs, but since you have no C++14 you could create a lock-counting wrapper around `std::mutex` and use that:

```
// Lock-counting class
class SharedLock
{
public:
   SharedLock(std::mutex& m) : count(0), shared(m) {}

   friend class Lock;

   // RAII lock
   class Lock
   {
   public:
      Lock(SharedLock& l) : lock(l) { lock.lock(); }
      ~Lock()                       { lock.unlock(); }
   private:
      SharedLock& lock;
   };

private:

   void lock()
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(internal);
      if (count == 0)
      {
         shared.lock();
      }
      ++count;
   }


   void unlock()
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(internal);
      --count;
      if (count == 0)
      {
         shared.unlock();
      }
   }

   int count;
   std::mutex& shared;
   std::mutex internal;
};

std::mutex shared_mutex;

void A()
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(shared_mutex);
   // ...
}


void B()
{
   static SharedLock shared_lock(shared_mutex);
   SharedLock::Lock mylock(shared_lock);
   // ...
}
```

... unless you want to dive into Boost, of course.